# Switching 2 momentary outputs sequentially with one momentary input... how?

Tags: digital-logic, switches, relay

so I have two buttons I need to trigger momentarily with a relay for each, the triggering needs to be done with a foot pedal that has a NO and a NC state

with each press of the pedal it needs to activate alternately one of the two outputs momentarily

the power already available is 24v

Comment: Define the pulse width , delay and current  for each output

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to buy a commercially available alternating relay from an electrical distributor.